# Is it possible to disable or control "commands" in contentEditable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

As I understand it, an element with `contentEditable="true"` is some kind of WYSIWYG HTML editor. It generates relevant HTML tags corresponding to the command issued.

For example, if one selects text and then presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, the selected text is placed between `<b></b>` tags.

I need to have no style tags in the resulting text. How does one suppress, hijack or control the behavior of those commands?

Other things I could do:

- Filter out the tags after the fact; but then the user will think they have put things in bold when they really haven't
- Re-style the tags so that they don't show, and then filter them out; but there's a chance I might forget one, or that somehow the stylesheet is disabled
- Not use `contentEditable` at all but a `textarea` instead. But among other things, `contentEditable` makes it really easy to highlight the paragraph that is being edited. That's much more difficult to do with a `textarea`.

Comment: Just set `contentEditable="false"`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603822/5286034) answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the best landing page resource for contentEditable is here:

http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable

Basically, what it boils down to is this: You can not reconfigure the key codes themselves – they always exist, and they're different depending on localizations of browsers.

However, you can intercept the keyboard commands using JavaScript, an example of which can be seen here:

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js

I've been playing around with contentEditable lately with mixed success. Some things just tend to work better than others, and have mixed results across browser. If all you really want is an editor for contentEditable block elements, try taking a look at [aloha editor](http://aloha-editor.org/).

Comment: Thanks for this rapid answer; can I be notified when a command is run or do I have to listen to keystrokes?

Comment: It's an event listener – as far as I know, there's no notification involved except to the listener.

Comment: The html5 spec says at the end of 7.5.1: "All of the actions defined above, whether triggered by the user or programmatically (e.g. by execCommand() commands), must fire mutation events as appropriate." -- "All of the actions above" refer to all editing actions: insert, delete, enrich, etc. But "mutation events" seem to be seldom supported by the browsers, if at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're absolutely right. There's already an incorporated system for that. See here: http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2007/07/firefox-3-contentEditable/

Answer (score 23):

Rather than trying to suppress the unwanted tags via JavaScript, I just style them away and save/restore the un-styled text in the contenteditable region.

**Update** : Added pasted image suppression.

```css
[contenteditable] {
  background: #eee;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 1em;
}

[contenteditable] b {
  font-weight: normal;
}
    
[contenteditable] i {
  font-style: normal;
}

[contenteditable] img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: Wow, love your idea!

Comment: This works fine and I just used it, it should be noted however that this only applies to text, other behaviors such as images can still be copied  from external source and pasted into this area.

Comment: @JohnDavid I've now addressed the suppression of pasted images.

Answer (score 21):

I know it is too late, but if it can help some one It should worth give a try.

Here is how I handled it in `javascript`, to disable the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Any Key</kbd>), I've used:

HTML:

```
<div id="xyz" onKeyDown="return disable(this,event);" contentEditable="true">
This is my Rich Text Editor
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function disable(x,e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){ // .ctrlKey tells that ctrl key was pressed.
    return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/tFBKN/37/)

---

But this will also affect the default way of doing copy+paste using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. If you want to maintain all the default functionality except for special cases like: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>(**Bold**), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>(*italics*) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>(Underline), then it is better to use `switch case statements` on `keyCode` values like:

```
function disable(x,e){
   var ret=true;
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 66: //ctrl+B or ctrl+b
            case 98: ret=false;
                     break;
            case 73: //ctrl+I or ctrl+i
            case 105: ret=false;
                      break;
            case 85: //ctrl+U or ctrl+u
            case 117: ret=false;
                      break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
} // This will work fine for ctrl+c and ctrl+v.
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/tFBKN/38/)

---

Now this will work fine for the default functionality of doing copy+paste but will restrict others like bold, italics and underline.

---

**EDIT**

As [`Betty_St`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595152/betty-st) [Suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/41868109?noredirect=1), To make this work on Mac You need to replace:

```
if(e.ctrlKey){
```

with

```
if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){ // Coz You'll be using CMD key on mac
```

Then That Might work on Mac OS.

Note: I've not dealt with Mac previously, So I don't know whether that is right way of doing or not.

---

Hope it helps :). Cheers.

Comment: nice idea! I could use this to simulate a textarea that allows richer presentation but still restrict what can be shown/edited.

Comment: with mac I had to use ``e.metaKey`` because you will use CMD+B for making a text bold! so I made ``e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey``

Answer (score 5):

In React we use next code to disable all except Copy / Paste and move commands:

```js
const onKeyDown = (e) =>
  e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey
  && ![`c`, `v`, `ArrowLeft`, `ArrowRight`].includes(e.key)
  && e.preventDefault()

const App = props => (
  <div
    contentEditable
    suppressContentEditableWarning
    
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}    
  >
    12345
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not working. Still can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>B</kbd>...

Comment: It seems you forgot the parentheses, should be (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)
  && ![`c`, `v`, `ArrowLeft`, `ArrowRight`].includes(e.key)
  && e.preventDefault()

Also, I would suggest enabling Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Y as well