# How to inactivate contentEditable

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a webpage with an `img`. Each time the user clicks on the `img`, it will generate a `span` tag with the `contentEditable` attribute set to `true`.

My problem is that if the user clicks on the `img` to add a `span`, clicks on the `span` (thus activating the editable zone), then clicks back on the `img`, it will add another editable `span` (desired effect) but it will also leave the first `span` in edit mode.

How can I change back the editable `span` into a normal `span`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove the `contenteditable` attribute and the focus with jQuery like this:

```
$('span#id').removeAttr('contenteditable').blur();
```

If you want to style all spans that can be edited you can do it like this in CSS:

```
span[contenteditable] { } /* editable */
```

Comment: oups, no it doesn't.. Removing the attribute prevents it form being edited again (which isn't the desired effect but I could add it back another way so if it was the only problem I wouldn't mind), but it keeps the text selected (but it can't be edited as stated above) which is not desired.

Comment: You should ask your questions more precisely then. You asked: `How to inactivate contentEditable` / `How can I change back the editable span into a normal span?` and that's exactly what I answered.

Comment: true, what I meant by normal span was one that was not being edited. As I stated above, your solution get us 50% there because the span is still looking as if it was being edited, it is just that we can't modify its content.

Comment: I added a little bit to my answer. Does this answer all of it?

Comment: I changed my approach to use textarea instead of content editable (had some other issues with it), but I will keep this in mind. Thx.

Comment: For future reference, you can add back contenteditable using `.attr("contenteditable", true);`.